# Constrained search queries in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Does solr give constrained search result.For example I have a document with content "Credit risk is different from credit risk assessment".
Now if I query for "credit risk" , the frequency should be 1 since credit risk is different from credit risk assessment.

I have tried using different tokenizers but I didn't achieve my result

Comment: could you please elaborate? Its sort confusing what is the problem...Please do share the field type used for the field

Comment: Field type is TextField

Answer (score 0):

Use the tokenizer for exact match and change as per your use.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html
Example:

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```